# Jolt Spec - String to integer with if-else

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

## Input json

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "a",
      "dt": "2019-04-09 16:57:39"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "b",
      "dt": "2019-04-09 16:57:39"
    }
  ],
  "type": {
    "id": 4,
    "name": 12,
    "dt": 93
  }
}
```

## Target spec function

If `$.type.<any_column>` equals to `4` then cast `$.data.*.<any_column>` to `Integer`. (columns name are uncertain)

## Target json

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "a",
    "dt": "2019-04-09 16:57:39"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "b",
    "dt": "2019-04-09 16:57:39"
  }
]
```

Comment: have you got an answer now? Is question still actual?

Comment: Not yet, do you?

Answer (score 0):

Construct a tree going towards inner of the JSON for the keys such as `type` -> `id` -> `4` (*the value for the case expression*), and then call the array `data`  grabbing from ***4*** level up through use of `"@(4,data)"` handle such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "type": {
        "id": {
          "4": {
            "@(4,data)": {
              "*": {
                "*": "[&1].&"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[image]